# nested CSS counters in IE 7 without lists

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7, counter

I have the following HTML-code-structure (example):

```
<p paraclass="M">Some Text</p>
<p paraclass="A1">enum 1</p>
<p paraclass="A1">enum 2</p>
<p paraclass="A2">enum 2.1</p>
<p paraclass="A2">enum 2.2</p>
<p paraclass="A1">enum 3</p>
```

and want it to be rendered like this:

```
Some Text
1 enum 1
2 enum 2
   2.1 enum 2.1
   2.2 enum 2.2
3 enum 3
```

This works great with CSS-pseudotag like:

```
p[paraclass="A1"]:before{
   content:counter(A1);
   counter-increment:A1;
   counter-reset: A2;
 }
```

Unfortunatly this doesn't work in IE7.
 What is a good solution for this to work in IE7 without changing the HTML?
For a JS solution I have all the information about the counters I need (like the Id's, what counters they reset and what list-style-type they have). Is there a better/easier way? And if not, how can I use counterstyles like "lower-roman" without implementing them myself?
 Note: jQuery 1.6.2 can be used.

Comment: "Without changing the HTML" - we can't alter it through jQuery too?

Comment: It is possible to change the HTML, but I would like to know if there's an easy way without doing that.

Comment: I'd transform your code into nested ordered lists. That's what they are for, you completely miss the semantics here. Moreover `paraclass` is not a valid attribute. In HTML5 you could use `data-paraclass` which is valid.

Comment: [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) is good and working utilty to emulate CSS3 selectors in IE 6-8. I guess you need something additional to add the counter-increment.

Comment: selectivizir doesn't support ":before" but still nice to know, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your HTML is not valid. The `paraclass` attribute must be renamed to `data-paraclass` in case you're developing with HTML 5, or add a namespace if you're developing with XHTML.

Second, the `<p>` element is not thought to be displayed as a list. Therefore I'd like to encourage you to use the `<ol>` element, since it is designed especially for this purpose and supported by all browsers.

Comment: Thank you. I get the HTML the way you see it there and the information about how the different paraclass-IDs should be displayed. Everything worked fine by just using CSS except in IE 7. I have to transform the Elements back to the same format after user interaction (it's used in ckEditor).

Comment: Which version of ckEditor are you using? As seen in the ckEditor demo, the latest version supports numbered lists and seems to generate valid source code.

Comment: It does support it, however I would have to transform the code seen in the example to contain the ol-elements and transform it back when saving the text.

Comment: I assume you have some text stored somewhere, which is then displayed by ckEditor. Why would you do the transformation?

Comment: because the HTML is the text and to display it correctly there are the paraclass-Attributes that I can create CSS-rules for

Comment: You cannot use CSS3 selectors in IE7, this will not work unless you use js fixes or the like. That's why you have to work with `<ol>` so you don't have to customize your paragraphs to behave like a list. This way you don't even have to style your numbered list because the browser already handles this for you.